# iPython notebook error - Notebook JSON is invalid: u'execution_count' is a required property

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error when running my iPython Notebook and was wondering if someone could help.

I have tried browsing in previous posts but couldn't find an answer. The noteboook does run in the end on the web browser but the error keeps appearing.

Error in console:

```
C:\Apps\Anaconda2\envs\simpleQT\python.exe
C:\Apps\Anaconda2\envs\simpleQT\Scripts\ipython-script.py notebook --no-browser --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 8888
[I 09:43:20.525 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 09:43:20.528 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Tanya.Sandoval\_QT\simpleQT
[I 09:43:20.528 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 09:43:20.528 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8889/
[I 09:43:20.528 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 09:43:37.553 NotebookApp] Notebook JSON is invalid: u'execution_count' is a required property

Failed validating u'required' in schema:
    {u'additionalProperties': False,
     u'description': u'Result of executing a code cell.',
     u'properties': {u'data': {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/misc/mimebundle'},
                     u'execution_count': {u'description': u"A result's prompt number.",
                                          u'minimum': 0,
                                          u'type': [u'integer', u'null']},
                     u'metadata': {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/misc/output_metadata'},
                     u'output_type': {u'description': u'Type of cell output.',
                                      u'enum': [u'execute_result']}},
     u'required': [u'output_type',
                   u'data',
                   u'metadata',
                   u'execution_count'],
     u'type': u'object'}

On instance:
    {u'data': {u'text/html': u'<div>\n<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Open</th>\n      <th>High</th>\n      <th>Low</th>\n      <th>Close</th>\n      <th>Volume</th>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>Timestamp</th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-02</th>\n      <td>15.90</td>\n      <td>15.95</td>\n      <td>15.30</td>\n      <td>15.55</td>\n      <td>1065</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-05</th>\n      <td>15.94</td>\n      <td>15.94</td>\n      <td>15.32</td>\n      <td>15.38</td>\n      <td>3710</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-06</th>\n      <td>15.60</td>\n      <td>15.90</td>\n      <td>15.43</td>\n      <td>15.69</td>\n      <td>4619</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-07</th>\n      <td>15.75</td>\n      <td>16.04</td>\n      <td>15.40</td>\n      <td>15.45</td>\n      <td>5956</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-08</th>\n      <td>15.40</td>\n      <td>15.45</td>\n      <td>14.49</td>\n      <td>14.76</td>\n      <td>8454</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-09</th>\n      <td>14.60</td>\n      <td>14.80</td>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>14.44</td>\n      <td>6846</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-12</th>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>13.70</td>\n      <td>13.94</td>\n      <td>10355</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-13</th>\n      <td>13.30</td>\n      <td>14.05</td>\n      <td>13.30</td>\n      <td>13.78</td>\n      <td>11341</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-14</th>\n      <td>13.90</td>\n      <td>14.25</td>\n      <td>13.20</td>\n      <td>13.28</td>\n      <td>11170</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-15</th>\n      <td>13.17</td>\n      <td>13.64</td>\n      <td>13.07</td>\n      <td>13.25</td>\n      <td>9745</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n</div>'},
     u'metadata': {},
     u'output_type': u'execute_result'}
[W 09:43:37.565 NotebookApp] Notebook notebook.ipynb is not trusted
[I 09:43:38.515 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c8c37658-b072-4a1d-87c5-0f862f514e44
```

Error in web browser:

```
Notebook Validation failed: u'execution_count' is a required property:
{
 "output_type": "execute_result", 
 "data": {
  "text/html": "<div>\n<table border=\"1\" class=\"dataframe\">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style=\"text-align: right;\">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Open</th>\n      <th>High</th>\n      <th>Low</th>\n      <th>Close</th>\n      <th>Volume</th>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>Timestamp</th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n      <th></th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-02</th>\n      <td>15.90</td>\n      <td>15.95</td>\n      <td>15.30</td>\n      <td>15.55</td>\n      <td>1065</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-05</th>\n      <td>15.94</td>\n      <td>15.94</td>\n      <td>15.32</td>\n      <td>15.38</td>\n      <td>3710</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-06</th>\n      <td>15.60</td>\n      <td>15.90</td>\n      <td>15.43</td>\n      <td>15.69</td>\n      <td>4619</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-07</th>\n      <td>15.75</td>\n      <td>16.04</td>\n      <td>15.40</td>\n      <td>15.45</td>\n      <td>5956</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-08</th>\n      <td>15.40</td>\n      <td>15.45</td>\n      <td>14.49</td>\n      <td>14.76</td>\n      <td>8454</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-09</th>\n      <td>14.60</td>\n      <td>14.80</td>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>14.44</td>\n      <td>6846</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-12</th>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>14.40</td>\n      <td>13.70</td>\n      <td>13.94</td>\n      <td>10355</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-13</th>\n      <td>13.30</td>\n      <td>14.05</td>\n      <td>13.30</td>\n      <td>13.78</td>\n      <td>11341</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-14</th>\n      <td>13.90</td>\n      <td>14.25</td>\n      <td>13.20</td>\n      <td>13.28</td>\n      <td>11170</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2009-01-15</th>\n      <td>13.17</td>\n      <td>13.64</td>\n      <td>13.07</td>\n      <td>13.25</td>\n      <td>9745</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n</div>"
 }, 
 "metadata": {}
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update**

Actually this error only happens when I run the jupyter/ipython notebook from the PyCharm editor. If I run it on a web browser the errors disappear. It seems PyCharm's notebook compatibility is still suffering from bugs...

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem after using PyCharm on a notebook.

I could make the error disappear in the browser by simply restarting the kernel, clearing all output and saving the notebook.

Restarting the kernel is done by going to the **Kernal** menu and then selecting **Restart & Clear Output**. See screenshot for an example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Pycharm the issue is most likely that there are cells that have not been run at all - as I have found suggested in the description of the [nbfixme](https://pypi.org/project/nbfixme/) package.

Manual solution would be making sure that all cells (including empty ones) were run at least once (so run or delete them) or to use the linked extension (that one I personally have not tried).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today when I was trying to write a script that does some semi-automatic editing of my ipython scripts.

You may read the file line by line in python, and do a str.replace('"execution_count": "null"', '"execution_count": null')
and write the output to a new file.

You may then open the new file in ipython notebook. It solved the problem for me. After all, a ipython notebook file is just a json file (which is no more than a bunch of nested dictionaries and lists).

Comment: Thanks! I actually then realised that editing ipython notebooks using the pycharm IDE produces this error (and a few others). I recommend then using the web browser instead only as it is less prone to errors!

Comment: I had this same error from opening a notebook accidentally in pycharm. any idea how to make it stop happening in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I lost a considerable bit of time with this problem. If all else fails, turn the cells into markdown (you can do this in Pycharm), and then save.

At this point it should open in the regular browser, and you can turn them back into code.

If you have the option of clearing all output and saving, that's easier (in my case that was not an option, wouldn't even load).

Comment: It seems the act of changing the cell type to Markdown in PyCharm clears the output associated with that cell, at which point you can use PyCharm to switch it back to Code immediately. It's still a drag but may be easier than switching to the web interface for the second step.

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to refresh Kernel and delete logs, and you shouldn't be seeing any issues